# How to reload a many to many navigation property in ASP.Net MVC3 using code first Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I am getting my feet wet trying to use code first Entity Framework with ASP.Net MVC3 with POCO classes. I am currently wrestling with how to recover from a DbUpdateConcurrencyException when the Entity involved has a NavigationProperty that involves a many to many relationship.

Say the Entity is called `Player` and has a Navigation property called `Clubs`. A Player can be a member of many Clubs and Clubs can have many members.

So let's say that while a user is editing (in a detached manner of course, this is a web application) his clubmemberships an administrator has cancelled some of his clubmemberships. On calling `SaveChanges()` the user code will correctly throw an `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.

What I want to do now is reload the Player Entity *including his Clubs*. Reloading the Player is easy enough with `dbContext.Entry(player).Reload()` but this does not repopulate the Clubs navigation property with the clubs that are available to him after the administrator's intervention.

Please help!

Comment: could you please support your question with source code?

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar problem before and the best/simplest solution I found for my case - given how EF decides to cache and reload entities - was to create an entirely new DbContext instance and re-load the data using that.

Comment: Thanks! But that would be very bad if it is the only soltuion, right?

Comment: Well, that was the simplest thing that worked for my scenario. I remember working through a couple other ideas at the time though. I'll see if I can find those and update my answer with some more options. :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
dbContext.Entry(player).Reference(a => a.Clubs).Load()
```